# How can I validate intermediate text via a DTD?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd, dtd-parsing

My XML-DTD failed to validate this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE init[
<!ELEMENT init(a)>
<!ELEMENT a(b,c,(d|e))>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT c (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT d (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT e (#PCDATA)>
]>
<init>
<a>
dolor
<b> Lorem </b>
dolor
<c> Ipsum </c>
<d> hi </d>
dolor
</a>
</init>
```

How can I validate the intermediate text via a DTD?

PD:
Sorry, I edited the question -- my problem was not solved.

PD2:
I use this for validation dtd-html: http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of things:

1. You need to add spaces between your element names and the content model (the left parenthesis).
2. You need to declare `a` as a [mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-mixed-content) model.

Example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE init [
<!ELEMENT init (a)>
<!ELEMENT a (#PCDATA|b|c)*>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT c (#PCDATA)>
]>
<init>
    <a>
        dolor
        <b> Lorem </b>
        dolor
        <c> Ipsum </c>
        dolor
    </a>
</init>
```

Example #2...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE init [
<!ELEMENT init (a)>
<!ELEMENT a (#PCDATA|b|c|d|e)*>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT c (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT d (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT e (#PCDATA)>
]>
<init>
    <a>
        dolor
        <b> Lorem </b>
        dolor
        <c> Ipsum </c>
        <d> hi </d>
        dolor
    </a>
</init>
```

Comment: I change question , but you solution is good for case before.

Comment: @CodeNoob - `a` is still a mixed content model and has to be declared a certain way. I added a second example. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-mixed-content for more info.